# How should git username and email be configured when used in a pipeline script on an Azure Devops self hosted agent server?

Tags: git, azure-devops

I am running a bash script in an Azure Devops pipeline where I ned to use git. [The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/git-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic) say:

> Before you begin, be sure your account's default identity is set with:

```
git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

They also say:

> Undo git config changes.

If I configure git as if it were me, which I should, it is fine if I set the config back to how it was before. So in my script I add a line `git config --list` to find out what the default username and email should be but it looks like this:

```
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.url=xxxxx
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
gc.auto=0
branch.xxxxxxxx.remote=origin
branch.xxxxxxxx.merge=refs/heads/xxxxxx
```

This does not include the email and username but when I use this command on my local machine I can see them.

I have tried configuring git with a non-local username and email like this:

`$ git config --global user.name "John Doe"`

But I get the error:

> fatal: could not read Username

Why does `git config --list` return this configuration and is it safe to set the config back to an empty string?

Comment: Hi @Mr.Robot, Is the explanation in my answer helpful to you? If you have any questions about this, feel free to tell me.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have configured your self-hosted agent to run as a service, right?

There are few points you need to know:

1. The '**`git config --list`**' command is reading the information from three different places (more details, see [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup)).

   - **`[path]/etc/gitconfig`** file.
   - **`~/.gitconfig`** or **`~/.config/git/config`** file.
   - config file in the Git directory (that is, **`.git/config`**) of whatever repository you’re currently using.
2. The user information (**`user.name`**, **`user.email`**) you set via the '**`git config --global`**' command is stored in the '**`~/.gitconfig`**' or '**`~/.config/git/config`**' file. According to the introduction of this file, it stores the **values specific personally to you, the user**.

   Any user who has logged in to the computer and set the '**`git config --global`**' will have this **`gitconfig`** file generated on the computer system (e.g. '**`C:/Users/{username}/.gitconfig`**' on Windows computer). And each user only can access his own **`gitconfig`** file.
3. If configure a self-hosted agent to run as a service, the agent is a Network Service on the system. It also has its own **`gitconfig`** file (e.g. '**`C:/WINDOWS/ServiceProfiles/NetworkService/.gitconfig`**' on Windows computer). The agent also can only access its own **`gitconfig`** file.

   Due to you have not set the '**`git config --global`**' via the agent, the **`gitconfig`** file has not generated for the agent. So the '**`git config --list`**' command will only read the information from other two files.
4. Once you set the '**`git config --global`**' via the agent, the configuration will be preserved. This means any other users who can trigger the pipeline will be able to use the '**`git config --list`**' command to read your user information. This may cause risks for your user information. So it recommends you **undo git config changes** at the end step of the pipeline.